# Jsoup: change a tag with a text then save in Java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a html file:

```
<html ><head></head> <body> <dtag> <div>TEST</div> </dtag> </body></html>
```

I want to  replace whole `<dtag>`, include content inside it, by  text as "adc"
 and save it. I am using this function:

```
private void editHTML() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strIndexPath));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(strLine);
    }
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString());
    // Document doc=Jsoup.parse(strIndexPath,"UTF-8");
    String tagName = "dtag";
    Elements dTags = doc.select(tagName);
    if (dTags != null)
        messager.show(dTags.toString());
    String strPhp = "<?php $this->DoIt();?>";
    for (Element dTag : dTags)
        dTag.text(strPhp);
    messager.show(dTags.toString());
}
```

I knew that I did it. But I don't know how to save it into my html file.

Comment: `Document doc` stores structure of your updated HTML. You can simply take results of its `doc.toString()` method and store it in your file. Usually to update content of text file we are creating temporary file, store entire updated content there, delete original file (you may need to close it first) and rename temporary file to original one.

Comment: but the output made "<"  into " &lt;". i don't know how to make it into "<" in output.

Comment: and how to vote/like your answer???

Comment: `.text("new text")` can only set text and to represent `<` as text we should use `&lt;` and `&gt;` for `>`. If you want to add HTML elements you would need to use `append`. But I am afraid that you will not be able to add `<?php...?>` using jsoup since it is not proper HTML tag (but I may be wrong).

Comment: Thank a lot for your helping.

Comment: i really want to vote for u but don't know how.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges you would be able to upvote answers if you will get 15 reputation points. But another problem here is that I didn't post answer but *comment* since I am not really sure that what I am saying about that you can't do it in Jsoup is true. I just tried to explain possible reasons of why you could have problems with achieving your goal.

Comment: @Pshemo `<?php...?>`can be replaced by `<script language=php>...</script>`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37022484/363573.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a PHP version older than `7.0.0`, you can use this php start tag `<script language=php>` instead of `<?php`.

This different php start tag will make Jsoup happy:

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String s = "<html><head></head> <body> <dtag> <div>TEST</div> </dtag> </body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s, "", Parser.xmlParser());

System.out.println("BEFORE:\n" + doc.html());

Elements dTags = doc.select("dtag");
for (Element dTag : dTags) {
    dTag.after("<script language=php>$this->DoIt();</script>");
    dTag.remove();
}

System.out.println("\n\nAFTER:\n" + doc.html());
```

#### OUTPUT

```
BEFORE:
<html>
 <head></head> 
 <body> 
  <dtag> 
   <div>
    TEST
   </div> 
  </dtag> 
 </body>
</html>


AFTER:
<html>
 <head></head> 
 <body> 
  <script language="php">$this->DoIt();</script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

References:

- [PHP tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)